# не активен QMenuBar

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

[вот тут](https://github.com/artur1214/cppMainAsks) лежит мой проект (в `src` лежат исходники, а в `mainProject` файл `notepad6d11` это собранная версия), проблема: верхняя панель (там где `файл` поле) не нажимается, но если перенести в текстовое поле какой-нибудь файл, то все начинает работать, я не могу найти ошибку
P.S. тестировал на 2 компьютерах, видимо проблема не в моей кривой сборке

Comment: Давайте [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) :)

Comment: Ваша ссылка битая , к тому же врядли кто-то в здравом уме будет скачивать и запускать неизвестный бинарь себе на комп, чтобы проверить ваш баг

Comment: Ссылку я исправил, а качать ничего и не надо, в исходниках есть текстом вся программа, в конце концов как я вам должен показать ошибку иначе? В designer'е есть возможность создать qmenubar, что я и сделал, он отображается, но не нажимаются кнопки

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас, судя по всему, лейбл `l` перекрывает главное меню. Перенесите добавление лейбла в статусбар сразу после создания лейбла:

```
....
this->setFixedSize(this->size());
l = new QLabel(this);
ui->statusBar->addWidget(l);
```

Вы добавляете лейбл после открытия файла, причем каждый раз, это неправильно

Comment: это действительно сработало! Но объясните пожалуйста, почему после открытия файла проблема решалась сама собой?

Comment: не сама собой, а потому что помещение лейбла, перекрывающего меню, в статусбар у вас было как раз при открытии файла